# ftp_get can't connect to file/ directory

Tags: php, ftp, server

I'm connecting to FTP server and trying to download a file from it, but I'm getting an error of

> Warning: ftp_get() [function.ftp-get]: Can't open /home/a*******/public_html/files/test.txt: No such file or directory in /home/a*******/public_html/MainHomescreen.php on line 213

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['download']))    
{
    // connect and login to FTP server
    $ftp_server = "********.*****.***";
    $ftp_username = "a*******";
    $ftp_userpass = "******";

    $ftp_conn = ftp_connect($ftp_server) or die("Could not connect to $ftp_server");
    $login = ftp_login($ftp_conn, $ftp_username, $ftp_userpass);

    if(isset($_POST['checkbox']))
    {
        foreach($_POST['checkbox'] as $selected)
        {
            //echo $selected;

            $local_file = "local.zip";
            $server_file = "/home/a*******/public_html/files/$selected";

            // download server file
            if (ftp_get($ftp_conn, $local_file, $server_file, FTP_BINARY))
            {
                echo "Successfully written to $local_file.";
            }
            else
            {
                echo "Error downloading $server_file.";
            }
        }
    }
    // close connection
    ftp_close($ftp_conn);
}
```

it's connecting to the server ok as I've checked that but when I try and download a file it comes up with the error above, but does echo the error line too. I'm not sure whether I've connected to it wrong in $local_file and $server_file, which is my best bet as to where I've gone wrong. Hoping someone might be able to help. Thanks.

Comment: Does the FTP user have the right file permissions to access that file?

Comment: @HermannStephaneNtsamo How would I check the file permissions?

Comment: If you have SSH access to the server you can use the command "ls -lha", if not you can use an FTP client like filezilla to test if using the username and password you used in the code you can effectively download the file over FTP. If you cannot download the file with the FTP client, then it means the FTP user does not have the right to download that file. And you should change the permission before you can access it over FTP.

Comment: I've set all file permissions to 777 but still no luck - also put the full bit of code in. Not sure if it's because I'm not pointing to the right folder/ how as the directory it's say it's not in isn't where it should be updated with this too

Comment: This is a very dangerous piece of code to write, you are essentially allowing anybody to download any file on you server. I would suggest that you validate $_POST['checkbox'] and make sure that it has one of the expected value. So if an attacker post "../../config.php" into checkbox or anything of the sort it will not download it. But security aside, if you can confirm that the file: "/home/a******/public_html/files/test.txt" exists on the server and it is chmod to 777 (which should not be needed), try to make the FTP user the owner of that file and try again. You can use the command "chown"

Comment: It's a user/password protected system etc, this is just the main screen after login in in theory is secure. Still not having any luck.

Comment: Current directory just shows as '/' which is where my issue is, but can't seem to change it using chdir